# How to animate the size changed event of a visual element in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, maui

Let's say I have a page with a grid consisting of 2 rows, and a button which modifies the grid size by adding a 3rd row, or removing the 3rd row if it has already been added, like this:

```cs
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = parentGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
    
    if (count == 2)
    {
        parentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(GridLength.Star));
    }
    else
    {
        parentGrid.RowDefinitions.Remove(parentGrid.RowDefinitions[count - 1]);
    }
}
```

```xml
<Grid x:Name="parentGrid" RowDefinitions="40, *">
    <Button Text="Change grid" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <ProgressCircle Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Now, the height of the element contained in the first row of the grid will be impacted whenever the button is clicked and will either increase or decrease.

What I am trying to achieve is to animate that height increase/decrease, for example doing something like this:

```cs
public ProgressCircle()
{
    SizeChanged += ProgressCircle_SizeChanged;
}
    
private void ProgressCircle_SizeChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here I would like the circle to slowly either shrink or increase to its target dimension.
    this.ScaleTo(1, 2000);
}
```

I just started using animations though and I'm not sure how to approach this, thanks in advance for any input on this.

Comment: When the size has changed, it already has its target size. The event handler might get called multiple times, because visual element sizes can be updated multiple times during a layout cycle. You might cause an infinite loop by animating (= changing) the size inside of the `SizeChanged` event handler.